# Uniqe constrain on condition psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I required to implement unique constrain on psql table
i have columns,

1) date
2) employee
3) client_id
4) start_time

trying to add two constrain like,
1) check unique rule for date, employee, start_time, client_id this will simply work with unique constrain

BUT SECOND CONSTRAIN Is for condition where we already create entry with date,employee,start_time and client_id is False

-> so if someone try to create same entry we require to check constrain like,
 does any entry already exist with fields "date, employee_id,start_time" AND client_id= False

> in SIMPLE words
>
> 1) check if all 4 fields exist with unique constrain        > display warning record exist
>
> 2) check if record with 3 fields and client_id = null exist > display warning record exist assign client_id

if anybody have little hint
it would be helpful

Comment: Won't unique constraints for 4 columns work in both cases? It seems to me like you are comparing 4 columns with second condition.

Comment: yes but i have two cases if i use 4 column in unique constrain it will also checked for record client_id is False and that time i want to provide different message warning.@ŁukaszKamiński Updated question tried to explain problem in simple way plz check :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need partial indexes. One will cover case when client_id is provided and other will deal with NULL client_id.

```
create table uni(val1 int, val2 text, val3 date, client_id int);

create unique index record_exists on uni(val1, val2, val3, client_id)
 where client_id is not null;

create unique index record_exists_assign_client_id on uni(val1, val2, val3)
 where client_id is null;

insert into uni values (1, 'test', current_date, 43), (2, 'test2', current_date, null);
--OK

insert into uni values (1, 'test', current_date, 43);
--duplicate key value violates unique constraint "record_exists"

insert into uni values (1, 'test', current_date, null);
--OK

insert into uni values (2, 'test2', current_date, null);
--duplicate key value violates unique constraint "record_exists_assign_client_id"
```